# Can I return a PreparedStatement after prepareStatemet using connection in java method?

Tags: java, mysql

I want to return the `preparedStatment` Like below. So can I execute the `preparedStatment` in another class?

```
package com.prs.dao.client;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import com.prs.model.ClientBean;
import com.prs.utils.DBclass;

public class ClentQueries {

    /*
     * singleton connection
     */
    DBclass dBclass = DBclass.getInstance();
    Connection connection = dBclass.getConnection();

    /**
     * <p>Insert Client</p>
     * @param clientBean
     * @return preparedStatement of insert Query
     */
    public PreparedStatement insertClient(ClientBean clientBean){
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement=null;
        try
        {
        String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO clients(firstName, lastName, email, password, birthday, phone, address)"
                + " VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(insertQuery);
        preparedStatement.setString(1, clientBean.getFirstName());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, clientBean.getLastName());
        preparedStatement.setString(3, clientBean.getEmail());
        preparedStatement.setString(4, clientBean.getPassword());
        preparedStatement.setString(5, clientBean.getBirthday());
        preparedStatement.setString(6, clientBean.getPhone());
        preparedStatement.setString(7, clientBean.getAddress());

        return preparedStatement;
        }catch(SQLException exception){
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
        return preparedStatement;
    } 

}
```

Then I want to execute the `preparedStatement` like this.

```
public class UseClientDao {

    public int addClient(PreparedStatement preparedStatement) {
        int numOfRow =0;
        numOfRow = preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        return numOfRow;
    }
    //call method
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would advise against this.  You should not be passing any artifacts like `Statement` or `ResultSet` out of a method, because it's not clear whose responsibility it is to close the resource.  They should be created in a method, used, and closed in the same method scope.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can return the Prepared Statement Object .

[Prepared Statement Link](https://www.javatpoint.com/PreparedStatement-interface)